# How to update user name in acl_sid table that is part of Spring Security ACL?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-security, acl

ACL_SID table that is used in Spring security ACL contains name of the user as one of the columns. I am wondering about the best way to modify this value. This is necessary for example when a user name corresponding to an already existing user is changed. It doesn't look like `JdbcMutableAclService` supports this functionality. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `JdbcMutableAclService` class and add new method that is needed.

In your constructor you can create instance of `JdbcTemplate`:

```
public YourClassName(DataSource dataSource, LookupStrategy lookupStrategy, AclCache aclCache) {
    super(dataSource, lookupStrategy, aclCache);
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    this.aclCache = aclCache; 
}
```

Now you can use that `JdbcTemplate` in your new method to update SID's username.

```
jdbcTemplate.update("update acl_sid set sid = ? where sid = ?", newUsername, oldUsername);
```

Remember about unique constraint

```
constraint unique_uk_1 unique(sid,principal)
```

`JdbcTemplate` can throw `DataAccessException` in case of failure. For instance `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown when SID with that name already exists in your database.

Also remember about transactions.

As you can see Spring Security is using `AclCache` to perform more efficiently. You'd better evict everything from that cache on every username update. You can use `void clearCache();` method for that. `AclCache` is a private member of your superclass so you need to remember that instance inside your class (look at suggested constructor's body).